# How do I import a PowerShell module for use by a pipeline task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm creating a Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps. I have a PowerShell task that invokes a script inside a file - it's not "inline" PowerShell. That script needs the `Az.Accounts` module so I added `Import-Module Az.Accounts`. When I run the pipeline, I get the following:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
directory.
At D:\a\1\s\XXX\XXX\XXX.ps1:14 char:1
+ Import-Module Az.Accounts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Az.Accounts:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

How do I add the missing module so my script can run?

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: This is a hosted VS2019 on Windows agent.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By default, the hosted windows agent just include the AzureRM module, which is older.With the Az module, Azure PowerShell is now compatible with PowerShell 5.1 on Windows and PowerShell Core 6.x and later on all supported platforms - including Windows, macOS, and Linux.It is the biggest and most important change.

You can add an inline powershell task for installing the `Az.Accounts` module. [image]

Please note that if you don't add the `-force` parameter in the script, you will get this information in process.

```
User declined to install module (Az.Accounts).
```

Comment: Does this mean that the module is installed for each run? In which case, this step will take quite a while as the `Az` module is pretty big.

Comment: you will need to use -Confirm option NOT -Force

Comment: According to Microsofts documentation,  the '-Confirm' option "Prompts you for confirmation before running the Install-Module cmdlet".

Answer (score 6):

When using Azure Devops with the hosted windows-2019 image, I recommend you use the "AzurePowerShell" task instead of the plain "PowerShell" task, with a version @4 or higher.

[documentation of this task can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell). Scroll down to see the options related to versioning.

Syntax and arguments are almost identical to the PowerShell task, except that you no longer need to login in Azure (you provide a service connection in the parameters).

You don't need to do crazy stuff like installing the Az module or uninstalling AzureRM. If you use the AzurePowerShell task, it's available for you.

note: don't use Az commands and AzureMR (deprecated) commands in the same script.

Comment: What if the ServiceConnectios are not allowed by oraganization? We are required to use use Service Principals and Secrets exclusively.

Comment: That sounds like a weird policy, because Service Connections ARE nothing else than just a Service Principal and a secret. What's the difference?

If you don't want to setup a Service Connection, you will need to setup a Service Principal and secret and read it's info (ID and secret) from the variables of the pipeline and use them in your script to setup the authentication. But that's exactly the problem that Service Connections simplify for you...

Answer (score 2):

The hosted agents don't have the `Az` modules installed -- they have the older `AzureRM` modules.

You should be able to use `Install-Module` to install them. Or you can rewrite your scripts to use `AzureRM`.